# How to add new sites and map a custom domain in WordPress Multisite?

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping

I have a wordpress multisite installation on a domain.
I defined each site as a sub-domain.
**For Example:**
www.example.com -- Main Domain
www.test1.example.com --- is the another site similarly I have another 4/5 sites that uses single installation of wordpress ( WPMU )
Now I want to add a fully qualified domain such as 
www.mydomain.com to www.test1.example.com

I have tried using parked domain in cPannel of my web host, But it's not possible as the sub-domains are virtually created by wordpress.

In number of forums, I read there is a plugin (WordPress MU Domain Mapping), but I don't want to depend on any 3rd party script.

is there any way?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 2):

Domain mapping allows a blog on a multisite install to serve from any domain name. This way a blog does not have to be a subdirectory of the main install, or a subdomain. The WordPress Default supports Domain Mapping without Alias. Add the Domain in the blog-settings to the blog of the Network administration area.

Often is it helpful - but not necessary, to set the `COOKIE_DOMAIN` constant to an empty string in your `wp-config.php`:

`define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', '' );`

Otherwise WordPress will always set it to your network’s `$current_site->domain`, which could cause issues in some situations.

WordPress Core hopes to provide Domain Alias Mapping in the future, but until then you can make use of one of the following plugins:

- https://github.com/humanmade/Mercator
- https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/

Comment: Dear which one is best?

Comment: If you don't use a alias domain, then it works WITHOUT a plugin. For me is the source of Mercator much better, but Domain Mapping is old, works and maintain.

Comment: My domain is http://odia-sahitya.ejajpur.in/ and I want to add http://odiasahitya.in/

Comment: I have installed https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/ still no result..........

Comment: Do you have read the [install](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/installation/). The plugin is not a default plugin, is a dropin.

Comment: Can you please Explain this
4-As a "super admin", visit Super Admin->Domain Mapping to create the domain mapping database table and set the server IP address or a domain to point CNAME records at.

Comment: Who is this super admin? and where I can find it... I am using cPanel with shared hosting environment...

Comment: I follow the instruction...after that http://www.odiasahitya.in showing error

Comment: The super admin is the access to the network area of the Multisite back end. Do you have active the Multisite Feature? Also read the codex about Multisite - http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19614/discussion-between-bikrampahi-and-bueltge).

Comment: Yes I have admin access......

Comment: Now it redirect me to signup page
http://ejajpur.in/wp-signup.php?new=www.odiasahitya.in

Comment: I think you don't understand the difference from Multisite to a default installation, single site. Read the codex about the network, see above the link. In the network admin can you set new sites to the network and add the domain, the url to this site. But I will not discuss about a helping inside the chat, not enough time for a support topic or training.