# WP 4.4 - domain mapping for sites within a multisite network?

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping

I've spent hours researching this and still no clarity.  I have a multisite installation, using subdomains.  The base site is:

```
www.foositenewtork.com
```

Sites inside the network are like this:

```
username.footsitenetwork.com
```

I want someone to be able to register their own domain and put this in their browser:

```
www.usernameownsite.com
```

and have it simply **work**.  I want to do this without relying on a plugin - although the plugin **WordPress MU Domain Mapping** looks to be pure genius, I read every line of code it contains and frankly it scares me.  I am trying to eliminate/minimize reliance on 3rd party code.

In researching, I have found questions like [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/172724/how-to-add-new-sites-and-map-a-custom-domain-in-wordpress-multisite) where the answer mentions this:

> WordPress Core hopes to provide Domain Alias Mapping in the future

So, where exactly are we with WP 4.4 and this functionality?  I could not find any documentation on this.

Closest thing I could find was [this discussion](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/10/28/multisite-focused-changes-in-4-4/); note the questions at the bottom and one about domain mapping which (as of right now) remains unanswered.  I've asked a question there too, it's awaiting moderation...

Comment: I used the MU Domain Mapping plugin on my multisite. Worked well. I figured why reinvent the wheel.... but if you want to build it into your code, probably doable with some effort. For me, I figured someone else's solution was good enough for me.

Comment: @RickHellewell - sorry this question should have been updated...I finally got to the right configuration, with no plugin.  You should not be using that plugin in any WP >= 4.5.x   see this: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/229486/domain-mapping-without-plugin-in-4-5-x-multisite/246814

Comment: Yes, know about domain mapping with current versions. You should add your answer to this question so it doesn't show up in the 'unanswered' queue.