# WordPress multisite with domains and subdomains

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping

I enabled multisite on my new project and have the following setup:

domain.com - central website
shop.domain.com - store
network.domain.com - BuddyPress install

Right now I need to add the following:
countrydomain.com - website for different country
and someday probably:
countryb.com - additional country / countries

Long story short, I need to use multisite with additional domains and subdomains. Everything works perfectly with subdomains, but when I try to add another domain, the most I can achieve is extra domain redirecting to subdomain.

Is there a way to map the domain to one of the sites in the network and how can you acomplish this without 3d party plugins?

Comment: Try searching for ccTLDs, i know this has been possible in core since 4.2

Answer (score 1):

Here are the high level steps if you are on 4.2 or greater:

1. Have your multisite hosted at a dedicated IP address.
2. Go into your network dashboard `My Sites > Network Admin > Sites` and edit the site you want to map, by changing its url to `http://example.com` (no www).
3. At the registrar for the domain, set an A record that points to the multisite dedicated IP address, and a CNAME record for WWW that points to the TLD for the domain (e.g. `CNAME www.example.com -> example.com`).
4. In your `wp-config.php` file set this line:  `define( 'COOKIE_DOMAIN', '' );`

Now, when you bring up `www.example.com`  or `example.com` in the browser it will be serving up `example.multisite.com` - and nobody will ever know; 100% domain mapped success.

Note that if you want to go next level with this and be a mapping superstar, you'll need to use [my instructions for leveraging AWS (or CloudFlare)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/229486/domain-mapping-without-plugin-in-4-5-x-multisite/246814#246814), and possibly running white-label nameservers.  With that scenario you don't even need the multisite at a dedicated IP address since you'd be using the AWS augmented "alias" record...but I still have mine at a dedicated IP address because some clients will still want to run DNS externally (e.g. Microsoft Office online...).